# Passing Variable from Python (win32) to Excel VBA Macro

Tags: python, excel, vba, winapi

I can't seem to figure out how to pass a variable correctly from python win32 to excel. I'm testing it using the below code

```
import win32com.client as win32

test1 = 5

xl = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\Users\XXX\PERSONAL.XLSB')
xl.Visible = False
xl.Application.Run("PERSONAL.XLSB!scratch.test", test1)
xl = 0
```

Where the scratch module looks like this

```
Sub test()

Dim test1 As Long

MsgBox (test1)

End Sub
```

I'm getting the error:
result = self.*oleobj*.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352562), None)

Ideally I have another file that is trying to pass through multiples lists as arguments. I couldn't figure that out so thought I'd try with something simpler.

Comment: If `test1` is the parameter, you would need to define your Sub something like this `Sub test(test1 as Long)` and get rid of the Dim statement.

Comment: Thank you very much! was stuck on this all morning

Comment: Note, VBA passes parameters `ByRef` unless specified otherwise. You might want to make that `ByVal test1 As Long`

Comment: Noted, thanks for the additional info